# How to change a list of tuples to a set in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I created a function in Python which returns a list of all the possible outcomes of throwing 2 dice. 
The list of tuples: [(1,1), (1,2), ..., (6,6)].

Then I wrote a function to find all elements of which the sum of the two values is even **(a)** and another one to find the elements of which the product of the values is even **(b)**.

Now I'm trying to write a function to find the elements that are only in **(a)** and another one to find the elements of which the product of the values is even in both **(a)** and **(b)**.

> ```
> def dice_outcomes():
>     outcomes=[]
>     for i in range (1,7):
>         for j in range (1,7):
>             outcomes.append((i,j))
>     r = outcomes
>     return(r)
>
> def filter_sumiseven(tuple):
>     elem1 = tuple[0]
>     elem2 = tuple[1]
>     return (elem1 + elem2)%2 == 0
>
> def filter_productiseven(tuple):
>     elem1 = tuple[0]
>     elem2 = tuple[1]
>     return (elem1 * elem2)%2 == 0
> ```

I tried to convert my list (see below) to a set but it still does not work. 
I first tried to make a variable a and b for the return of my 2nd and 3rd function but that didn't work. 
Could anyone explain how to get the correct output?

> ```
>  def only_as(a):
>      set_a = set(a)
>      set_b = set(b)
>      if set_a not in set_b: 
>          return set_a 
>      else: 
>          #DO NOT ADD
>
>
>  def a_and_b(a, b):
>      set_a = set(a)
>      set_b = set(b)
>      if set_a in set_b:
>          #print
>      if set_b in set_a :
>          #print
> ```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'?

Comment: @parchment I tried to improve the explanation and edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code to be:

```
from itertools import product

dice_outcomes = list(product(range(1, 7), repeat=2))
is_even = {el for el in dice_outcomes if sum(el) % 2 == 0}
product_is_even = {(fst, snd) for fst, snd in dice_outcomes if fst*snd % 2 == 0}
just_even = is_even - product_is_even
even_and_product = is_even & product_is_even
```